# Best data structured combined with sorted array that can insert/delete quickly

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting, data-structures, insert

I have an array of objects (lets say `ints`) which is in random order.

```
[3, 6, 1, 2, 4, 5, 9]             <- array
```

I also have a subset of these objects in an array that is **sorted**. This array is in a data structure class `CustomStruct` I am trying to `extend`.

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]                      <- sortedSubArray
```

The extended functionality of the data structure is to have some sort of list/tree that is **in order** (elements inserted correctly) and has very **fast insert/delete** operations.

An example scenario is:

I iterate through the `array` object and apply `customDataStruct.Add(obj)`.

The first element being `3` appears (result `3`)

Next element is `6` and is ignored since it is not in our `sortedSubArray`

Next element is `1`, using our `sortedSubArray` we know it needs to be inserted before `3`

(result `1 -> 3`)

Next element is `2`, which as we know from `sortedSubArray` is inserted before `3` and after `1`

(result `1 -> 2 -> 3`)

We decide `2` is no longer needed in our data structure and apply `customDataStruct.Remove(obj)`, (result `1 -> 3`)

Can I make use of the above `sortedSubArray` for this? Would it be efficient if I was to use the `sortedSubArray` combined with a singly linked list [combined with binary search, etc]? or would I end up having to iterate through the singly list each time I `Remove`, etc?

If I was to add another array of same length as `sortedSubArray` which keeps a `boolean` value of whether the current `int` is in the list, would that help?

```
e.g. [1, 2, 3, 4]               sortedSubArray
     [true, false, true, true]  boolArray
     1 -> 3 -> 4                customDataStruct
```

Is a B-tree or Fibonacci heap a good alternative for this? If I chose to use these, is there any need for the `sortedSubArray`?

Comment: Oh no ... I have a nice C++ solution for this (opened it when the question was still tagged as C++) ... using a std::list and a std::multiset.

Comment: Would you be able to share the C++ version? This is a general problem so could probably be converted between other languages, right?